# What is the correct way to call Win32 InvalidateRect to clear the client area using the Rust Crate for Windows?

Tags: winapi, rust

The following code leaves the client area unchanged.

```
fn ResetGame(hwnd: &HWND, next_char: &mut u32, game_grid: &mut [u32; 9], X: u32) {
    unsafe {
        *next_char = X;
        //println!("in ResetGame and next_char is {}", next_char);

        for i in 0..9 {
            game_grid[i] = 0;
        }
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, std::ptr::null_mut(), BOOL(1)); // TRUE ?
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post answers unless it's an actual answer. If problem is solved, you have to click the big check mark, to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[`InvalidateRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect)

> adds a rectangle to the specified window's update region. The update region represents the portion of the window's client area that must be redrawn.

It does not, by itself, change the contents of a window. It merely causes the system to generate a `WM_PAINT` message when no higher priority messages are in the message queue. It is the `WM_PAINT` (and `WM_ERASEBKGND`) message that's responsible for rendering the contents.

The actual call itself can be simplified by passing a `bool` value instead; a conversion from `bool` to `BOOL` is provided by the crate. The second argument is of type `*const RECT` so you can pass `std::ptr::null()`. In other words:

```rust
InvalidateRect(hwnd, std::ptr::null(), true);
```

It's probably also a good idea to check the return value of type [`BOOL`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Foundation/struct.BOOL.html).

Comment: fn ResetGame(hwnd: &HWND, next_char: &mut u32, game_grid: &mut [u32; 9], X: u32) {
    unsafe {
        *next_char = X;
        //println!("in ResetGame and next_char is {}", next_char);

        for i in 0..9 {
            game_grid[i] = 0;
        }
        //InvalidateRect(hwnd, std::ptr::null_mut(), BOOL(1)); // TRUE ?
        let ret = InvalidateRect(hwnd, std::ptr::null_mut(), true);
        let ret2 = UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        println!("InvalidateRect returns {:?} and UpdateWindow returns {:?}", ret, ret2);
    }